# Using $_GET function as security measure in PHP

Tags: php, security

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['page'];
?>
<?php if($page == 'somerandomtext') : ?>
<html>
</html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can this code work as a security measure, as long no one knows the 'somerandomtext' ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: Not really, it's not really security.  Try and imagine that someone wants to hack your page and builds a bot to spam it. How long would it take to guess your random text?

Comment: Technically, yes to some extent but probably not very well. Keep in mind that URLs and their GET parameters are all logged by the webserver and anyone you share the link will also have the secret displayed right there in plain text.  This is the same reason auth basic via the url (https://user:pass@sub.domain.tld) is generally a bad idea and no longer supported.  You should really implement better security via any other method.

Comment: What other security measures do you advice me to use, to hide an html code?

Comment: `<php` < is that a typo? It should read as `<?php`.

Comment: wouldn't class is as security, just poor designed routing. obscure or hidden routes are used all over the web for things like api callbacks.

Comment: @AlxTioltisan You can use auth basic directly from the web server for the least amount of effort implementing something secure.  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html or https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes, sorry. Meant to <?php *

Comment: Ok thanks, I had to be sure.

Comment: Should I create a login script, and put session, and as long you have that session you can view the page? Would be better?

Comment: How is the `page` parameter different from using an "api token" to authenticate for access to api calls? This seems just as reasonable and secure (as long as the protocol is https).

Comment: @alexis Well, sending an API token with every request _isn't_ particularly secure; but adding it to a human-accessed URL has additional problems, because URLs frequently show up in plain text in ways that a POST submission or custom header would not.

Comment: Sorry, I need to nitpick and clarify that `$_GET` is not a function. It's just the variable where PHP exposes parsed URL parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the user's point of view, your code would be accessed via a URL like this:

```
https://example.com/something.php?page=somerandomtext
```

To the user, that is no different from if the URL was this:

```
https://example.com/somerandomtext.html
```

So the same level of security could be achieved without PHP, just by renaming a file to a long name that's hard to guess.

As for how secure that is, you always have to consider *what threat you're protecting against*. A few threats that this will fail to protect against:

- Viewing the URL over somebody's shoulder
- Accessing somebody's bookmarks or browser history (where the "secret" URL will be in plain text)
- Intercepting (or just accidentally receiving) an e-mail with the link in

Comment: In fact this approach is more common that it may seem: think of WeTransfer or Teams links. But it really makes sense only in short-lived URLs or low-security scenarios.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, short-lived and/or single use URLs mitigate these problems a lot.